# Magento Change product type from simple to grouped magento keeping custom options

Tags: mysql, magento

I need to change hundreds of product types in Magento 1.8.0.0 from simple to grouped.
I would like to keep the custom option for the single product and convert them as associated products for the grouped one since I have the product code set to identify the matching.
I've written a super draft pseudocode to do this:

```
$collection=model::simple product && manufacturer && custom options!=null && (attributeset==pentolame || attributeset==gastronorm)
$product=collection->getProduct(sku);
foreach product as element:
    this.setType(grouped); 
    foreach this.custom_option as variant
        temp=variant.code;
        grouped_product.associated=temp;
    end foreach;
save grouped_product;   
end foreach;
```

I'm not very experienced with the documentation of Magento, could anybody help me reach this goal? Thanks